# ggplot2: Quick Heatmap Plotting, reshape?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to reproduce the heatmap presented on [this blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) by following their tutorial, but when I try to run their Jan 2010-code I get an error when asking for,

```
nba.m <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
     Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rescale"
```

Reproducible code is available on the [blog mentioned above](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)

I'm using ggplot2_0.9.0 and R 2.14.2. Also, I did read [this thread here on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406394/how-to-produce-a-heatmap-with-ggplot2).

Any ideas to what might be wrong?

Comment: I've run into a few similar problems, and I've often been able to fix them by explicitly loading `library(scales)`.

Comment: @Marius, thanks. That solved the problem, strange. Well, thanks!

Comment: package 'scales' is not automaticaly loaded by ggplot2 since version 0.9.

Comment: @Marius, could you add your comment as an answer? In that way Eric can point to your answer as the correct one, and we can vote on it, get's you some rep :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ggplot2 doesn't seem to be loading the `scales` library automatically anymore, so to use the `rescale` function, you have to explicitly load `library(scales)`.

When you get an error about a function not being found, the `??` command can help you find which package the function might be in, e.g. `??rescale`.