# asymmetric color distribution in scale_gradient2?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scale

Changing the upper limits for `scale_fill_gradient2` also effects the colorscaling for values < 0 as the color distribution around 0 seems to be always symmetrically, is there a way to get a asymmetric distribution of color values?

Here a minimal example of a plot using `geom_tile()`:

```
data <- read.csv("http://protzkeule.de/data.csv")
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = variable, y = meas)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

plot with symmetrical limits:

```
p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", guide = "colorbar",
                         limits = c(-0.1, 0.1))
```

but when changing the upper limit, the lower colormapping changes as well (watch the colorbar):

```
p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", guide = "colorbar",
                         limits = c(-0.1, 0.3))
```

Comment: I could be misunderstanding what you're looking for, but try passing `midpoint = -0.1` to `scale_fill_gradient2`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I meant `0.1`, not `-0.1` there obviously, but I'm thinking now that isn't what you were looking for anyway, based on Brian's answer.

Comment: why is the helpfile so poor for this functions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you want is `scale_fill_gradientn`. The arguments are not very clear (took me an hour or so to finally figure part of it out), though:

```
library("scales")
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue","white","red"), 
                         values = rescale(c(-.1,0,.3)),
                         guide = "colorbar", limits=c(-.1,.3))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think now I got it. Correct me if I am wrong but with `values` you assign the values that a color from the `colours` vector is mapped to? 
The the only thing I don't get is what happens if the vector passed to `values` has more elements than the vector passed to `colours`.

Comment: `values` and `colours` should have the same length. They are effectively paired, where the value corresponds to the color at that point, and everything between it and the next point is interpolated. I don't actually know what would happen if they were not the same length; it is at least conceptually an error, but I don't know if an actual error is thrown. In your example, -0.1 is mapped to blue, 0.0 is mapped to white, and 0.3 is mapped to red; values between -0.1 and 0.0 are interpolated between blue and white; values between 0.0 and 0.3 are interpolated between white and red.

Comment: @BrianDiggs I am using your solution in a similar way but is there a way to display the color bar discretely for the first handful of values? E.g. [the sepal length answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713456/easiest-way-to-discretize-continuous-scales-for-ggplot2-color-scales)

Comment: @tbone I don't know offhand. That would be worthy of its own question.

Comment: Update for anybody coming to this question after v 0.9, you'll have to do `library(scales)` to include the rescale command, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006317/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting-reshape

Comment: Absolutely fabulous! I have struggled to find a solution to this problem and this answer was great, thank you ;)