# Asymmetric midpoint in scale_fill_gradient2 results with trimmed color on the shorter edge

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Here is starting example I'm trying to modify:

```
library(reshape2)

data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cormat <- round(cor(data),2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(
  data = melted_cormat,
  aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)
) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(
    aes(Var2, Var1, label = value)
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = 'red',
    high = 'blue',
    mid = 'white', 
    midpoint = 0, # <-- look at this
    limit = c(-1, 1)
  )
```

This code creates a plot:

[image]

But when I change the only midpoint to `midpoint = -0.5` plot looks like:

[image]

In my opinion, the **output is not correct since I clearly stated `low = 'red'`** and in the plot the lowest value color is between red and white.

I'm looking for a solution how to maintain `midpoint = -0.5` and a full gradient from -1 (red) to -0.5 (white).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299705/asymmetric-color-distribution-in-scale-gradient2):

```
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
cormat <- round(cor(data),2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat, na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(
  data = melted_cormat,
  aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)
) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(
    aes(Var2, Var1, label = value)
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
   colors=c("red","white","blue"),
   values=rescale(c(-1,-0.5,1)),
   limits=c(-1,1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Now I know that this is possible with `scale_fill_gradientn` but I'm still investigating why `high` and `low` are so confusing when `midpoint` is asymmetric in `scale_fill_gradient2`.

Comment: @Everettss  OK. I understand. The `scale_fill_gradient2` function uses the rescaler  `rescale_mid` of the `scales` package. I think it could be interesting to understand how it works trying: `rescale_mid(seq(-1,1,length.out=11),c(0,1),c(-1,1),0)` and `rescale_mid(seq(-1,1,length.out=11),c(0,1),c(-1,1),-0.5)`. See also: `scales:::rescale_mid.numeric`