# Asymmetric scale_fill_gradient2 breaks and colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

First of all, I am aware that there are similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083239/asymmetric-midpoint-in-scale-fill-gradient2-results-with-trimmed-color-on-the-sh) on this topic.
However, I couldn't get the exact result I was looking for.

I am trying to follow an analysis from an old paper where the heatmap looks like this:

[image]

Note that the scale of the relative abundance is asymmetric, and the green color spectrum spread widely from 0 to 0.5 and almost does not change between 0.5. to 1

The scale I am looking for is:
0 - 0.0005 (black to darkgreen) 0.0005 - 0.001 (darkgreen to green)  0.001 - 1 (green)

where 0.001-0.1 should take a small portion in the color spectrum.

my data:

```
structure(list(Sample_ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("IgA-", 
"IgA+", "Lumen"), class = "factor"), OTU_index = c("a2fb93085ef90d85ce26b60b12598198", 
"a2fb93085ef90d85ce26b60b12598198", "a2fb93085ef90d85ce26b60b12598198", 
"a71cdb983f4aa92f7986bbba79bdf852", "a71cdb983f4aa92f7986bbba79bdf852", 
"a71cdb983f4aa92f7986bbba79bdf852", "2a33800972eebfd8eb952c1e66d47923", 
"2a33800972eebfd8eb952c1e66d47923", "2a33800972eebfd8eb952c1e66d47923", 
"55cea1dcc86e10b108b9392c1d32db87", "55cea1dcc86e10b108b9392c1d32db87", 
"55cea1dcc86e10b108b9392c1d32db87", "020d9f81bef9262a3ab5071ca9511c1a", 
"020d9f81bef9262a3ab5071ca9511c1a", "020d9f81bef9262a3ab5071ca9511c1a", 
"0fb2db1ddef94c9151ddad4b89516c19", "0fb2db1ddef94c9151ddad4b89516c19", 
"0fb2db1ddef94c9151ddad4b89516c19", "b20b8aa4bd244d965316a278875a1469", 
"b20b8aa4bd244d965316a278875a1469", "b20b8aa4bd244d965316a278875a1469", 
"ba5f9431d97db7fbaa8125bd2a2ef414", "ba5f9431d97db7fbaa8125bd2a2ef414", 
"ba5f9431d97db7fbaa8125bd2a2ef414", "249db27ea543f4f74d96cd8a4d1f8a5a", 
"249db27ea543f4f74d96cd8a4d1f8a5a", "249db27ea543f4f74d96cd8a4d1f8a5a", 
"ed7c0c6d0b49bdf4219d0ba156862b2d", "ed7c0c6d0b49bdf4219d0ba156862b2d", 
"ed7c0c6d0b49bdf4219d0ba156862b2d", "1510c9ae07e70a0b279453e4ef862698", 
"1510c9ae07e70a0b279453e4ef862698", "1510c9ae07e70a0b279453e4ef862698", 
"5a50ef393bb47b0401a5921d42df3a13", "5a50ef393bb47b0401a5921d42df3a13", 
"5a50ef393bb47b0401a5921d42df3a13", "b21bbd9f9a9ee207b793d76c06672371", 
"b21bbd9f9a9ee207b793d76c06672371", "b21bbd9f9a9ee207b793d76c06672371", 
"77934d18d930c4602bc8c79b132a3d9c", "77934d18d930c4602bc8c79b132a3d9c", 
"77934d18d930c4602bc8c79b132a3d9c", "dbbe9d87d7d35308dd7446315a66e29f", 
"dbbe9d87d7d35308dd7446315a66e29f", "dbbe9d87d7d35308dd7446315a66e29f", 
"e6b05a69bc7fa8dc428caa3d409c9fbb", "e6b05a69bc7fa8dc428caa3d409c9fbb", 
"e6b05a69bc7fa8dc428caa3d409c9fbb", "42690539aa399c812b99bc18ad34b6b7", 
"42690539aa399c812b99bc18ad34b6b7", "42690539aa399c812b99bc18ad34b6b7", 
"208fbec6e805a6273bdcf5f3b0a4e856", "208fbec6e805a6273bdcf5f3b0a4e856", 
"208fbec6e805a6273bdcf5f3b0a4e856", "1de19b0d7a171cdd32b4dff524e87db2", 
"1de19b0d7a171cdd32b4dff524e87db2", "1de19b0d7a171cdd32b4dff524e87db2", 
"4768917a0a9d8ca21f0b5c512d4ef5df", "4768917a0a9d8ca21f0b5c512d4ef5df", 
"4768917a0a9d8ca21f0b5c512d4ef5df", "f24fb97f9535ab02ce6f7913c70cc0ee", 
"f24fb97f9535ab02ce6f7913c70cc0ee", "f24fb97f9535ab02ce6f7913c70cc0ee", 
"b3da3555cadd21fa9ee11c955ceefe6d", "b3da3555cadd21fa9ee11c955ceefe6d", 
"b3da3555cadd21fa9ee11c955ceefe6d", "7d1056cdb2c52aaeebcc69fae394fce9", 
"7d1056cdb2c52aaeebcc69fae394fce9", "7d1056cdb2c52aaeebcc69fae394fce9", 
"052ba7abaeaa968c4f79e3f97d1f0a2f", "052ba7abaeaa968c4f79e3f97d1f0a2f", 
"052ba7abaeaa968c4f79e3f97d1f0a2f", "df3d6113f855e22f2a6d44e60f01baa7", 
"df3d6113f855e22f2a6d44e60f01baa7", "df3d6113f855e22f2a6d44e60f01baa7", 
"888fba9f2214d28155e89e7bdbee45a6", "888fba9f2214d28155e89e7bdbee45a6", 
"888fba9f2214d28155e89e7bdbee45a6", "a9a0015052b629976dfce94f3aa37c1c", 
"a9a0015052b629976dfce94f3aa37c1c", "a9a0015052b629976dfce94f3aa37c1c", 
"81b3925347c6126f2dfaa1c52749e211", "81b3925347c6126f2dfaa1c52749e211", 
"81b3925347c6126f2dfaa1c52749e211", "c9d862665050f543bf49e721ec5d0d2d", 
"c9d862665050f543bf49e721ec5d0d2d", "c9d862665050f543bf49e721ec5d0d2d", 
"9ca6cddd0fe3d71c618b52d4facec414", "9ca6cddd0fe3d71c618b52d4facec414", 
"9ca6cddd0fe3d71c618b52d4facec414", "e8ffca4f94ec58f2799a41d7023f7374", 
"e8ffca4f94ec58f2799a41d7023f7374", "e8ffca4f94ec58f2799a41d7023f7374", 
"5bba94db59051b57f82f82af2657751b", "5bba94db59051b57f82f82af2657751b", 
"5bba94db59051b57f82f82af2657751b", "085414bbd6ff66ce28c6e72552f6fe1e", 
"085414bbd6ff66ce28c6e72552f6fe1e", "085414bbd6ff66ce28c6e72552f6fe1e", 
"694f413b53b76692d2bf1cd02091399c", "694f413b53b76692d2bf1cd02091399c", 
"694f413b53b76692d2bf1cd02091399c", "e94a9da4bdf2d1d6fd8b6216ea53a5ab", 
"e94a9da4bdf2d1d6fd8b6216ea53a5ab", "e94a9da4bdf2d1d6fd8b6216ea53a5ab", 
"96f1df5356b17e2d4b6eefc878357fcb", "96f1df5356b17e2d4b6eefc878357fcb", 
"96f1df5356b17e2d4b6eefc878357fcb", "ba049349b7b31b2a76dc7f469e70a455", 
"ba049349b7b31b2a76dc7f469e70a455", "ba049349b7b31b2a76dc7f469e70a455", 
"17f166c05517c7b5deedcb96caeaa6ce", "17f166c05517c7b5deedcb96caeaa6ce", 
"17f166c05517c7b5deedcb96caeaa6ce", "e0425c9f83aeb3182d39686eb4c33fd9", 
"e0425c9f83aeb3182d39686eb4c33fd9", "e0425c9f83aeb3182d39686eb4c33fd9", 
"2c1ca646f21790c9fd0d628144304151", "2c1ca646f21790c9fd0d628144304151", 
"2c1ca646f21790c9fd0d628144304151", "5fc798b1df3bcda5e68c5d88d8d39402", 
"5fc798b1df3bcda5e68c5d88d8d39402", "5fc798b1df3bcda5e68c5d88d8d39402", 
"8ae3caba9b8bffe6cd0720d0bf0861b7", "8ae3caba9b8bffe6cd0720d0bf0861b7", 
"8ae3caba9b8bffe6cd0720d0bf0861b7", "68fa6eb93675602681b474cb0ce9048b", 
"68fa6eb93675602681b474cb0ce9048b", "68fa6eb93675602681b474cb0ce9048b", 
"916170a0b9c8f238e0e4ba6fd9a4434f", "916170a0b9c8f238e0e4ba6fd9a4434f", 
"916170a0b9c8f238e0e4ba6fd9a4434f", "82d62beac2026a93c81370ae3be39703", 
"82d62beac2026a93c81370ae3be39703", "82d62beac2026a93c81370ae3be39703", 
"79a9d2c3929074a416360f2c49d9e818", "79a9d2c3929074a416360f2c49d9e818", 
"79a9d2c3929074a416360f2c49d9e818", "1099950f329f9b0cc24b900fcc0a0d89", 
"1099950f329f9b0cc24b900fcc0a0d89", "1099950f329f9b0cc24b900fcc0a0d89", 
"c4fb58da9aff3c83c971c488ebd3cb70", "c4fb58da9aff3c83c971c488ebd3cb70", 
"c4fb58da9aff3c83c971c488ebd3cb70", "2d54bddc534353d4747ec1ffe430dfd1", 
"2d54bddc534353d4747ec1ffe430dfd1", "2d54bddc534353d4747ec1ffe430dfd1", 
"0debac7bda0e8a1808ee18f1fa0fff95", "0debac7bda0e8a1808ee18f1fa0fff95", 
"0debac7bda0e8a1808ee18f1fa0fff95", "c052a9548dafdb7e60155e80657eceeb", 
"c052a9548dafdb7e60155e80657eceeb", "c052a9548dafdb7e60155e80657eceeb", 
"877750a0b70e44cb26d356108387972e", "877750a0b70e44cb26d356108387972e", 
"877750a0b70e44cb26d356108387972e", "31ee661ac8be6d9acf84ee644cabd521", 
"31ee661ac8be6d9acf84ee644cabd521", "31ee661ac8be6d9acf84ee644cabd521", 
"0f3d5ab93a1bdff74c4c3fbe0ad3206b", "0f3d5ab93a1bdff74c4c3fbe0ad3206b", 
"0f3d5ab93a1bdff74c4c3fbe0ad3206b", "b7409db20419d9921bb75f9b0129d9ad", 
"b7409db20419d9921bb75f9b0129d9ad", "b7409db20419d9921bb75f9b0129d9ad", 
"850fc8381d6fc19a74e163682a3c65f4", "850fc8381d6fc19a74e163682a3c65f4", 
"850fc8381d6fc19a74e163682a3c65f4", "455113c04ae870bb6358d28eece40b64", 
"455113c04ae870bb6358d28eece40b64", "455113c04ae870bb6358d28eece40b64", 
"b0527c0e6ebd8747711f456340f5cf72", "b0527c0e6ebd8747711f456340f5cf72", 
"b0527c0e6ebd8747711f456340f5cf72", "b058bab03adbc1c975eab1ae3d772d2c", 
"b058bab03adbc1c975eab1ae3d772d2c", "b058bab03adbc1c975eab1ae3d772d2c", 
"9d1231e9a3e3361b978bbff3c3b158a8", "9d1231e9a3e3361b978bbff3c3b158a8", 
"9d1231e9a3e3361b978bbff3c3b158a8", "08ed17794e8af08e5f0fb28b4e415a5a", 
"08ed17794e8af08e5f0fb28b4e415a5a", "08ed17794e8af08e5f0fb28b4e415a5a", 
"c0a472775f09ea4c7c8618c1cccaddfd", "c0a472775f09ea4c7c8618c1cccaddfd", 
"c0a472775f09ea4c7c8618c1cccaddfd", "0da03528d09c7777b72cdb2195beab99", 
"0da03528d09c7777b72cdb2195beab99", "0da03528d09c7777b72cdb2195beab99", 
"15ab7ca6d18b935e7cddb7196cc5f8e0", "15ab7ca6d18b935e7cddb7196cc5f8e0", 
"15ab7ca6d18b935e7cddb7196cc5f8e0", "bd01119f1696ad8fb3394d742090be40", 
"bd01119f1696ad8fb3394d742090be40", "bd01119f1696ad8fb3394d742090be40", 
"cd33d521d1dfcb297336e993ca998d2d", "cd33d521d1dfcb297336e993ca998d2d", 
"cd33d521d1dfcb297336e993ca998d2d", "2d257553a6e4a29d1049474d2805c1fb", 
"2d257553a6e4a29d1049474d2805c1fb", "2d257553a6e4a29d1049474d2805c1fb", 
"973360718cfb0d1806d43527cb25adb3", "973360718cfb0d1806d43527cb25adb3", 
"973360718cfb0d1806d43527cb25adb3", "4e237c595da5cb9529b22d4795613121", 
"4e237c595da5cb9529b22d4795613121", "4e237c595da5cb9529b22d4795613121", 
"b8aac847144c04285bc3bb3f60a2782f", "b8aac847144c04285bc3bb3f60a2782f", 
"b8aac847144c04285bc3bb3f60a2782f"), Relative_abundance = c(0.0059270622690189, 
0.0114357436719894, 0.00927410919740604, 0.0264277247053901, 
0.0359807544801618, 0.0348650721706994, 0.0196639007042745, 0.0123422355484276, 
0.00697301443413988, 0.0552960044627292, 0.0278920577365595, 
0.0156892824768147, 0.00878599818701625, 0.00488111010389791, 
0, 0.00174325360853497, 0.00230109476326616, 0.00822815703228506, 
0.0306115333658741, 0.0121330451154034, 0.012063314971062, 0.0274736768705111, 
0.0103897915068684, 0.0105989819398926, 0.0283104386026079, 0.0121330451154034, 
0.0158984729098389, 0.0309601840875811, 0.0105989819398926, 0.0104595216512098, 
0.00174325360853497, 0.0059270622690189, 0.00188271389721777, 
0.00271947562931455, 0.00313785649536295, 0.0445575622341538, 
0.0221044557562234, 0.0249633916742208, 0.0222439160449062, 0, 
0.00160379331985217, 0.00188271389721777, 0.0108779025172582, 
0.0140854891569626, 0.00948329963043023, 0.0056481416916533, 
0.00794923645491946, 0.00474164981521512, 0.0412802454501081, 
0.0352137228924064, 0.0297747716337773, 0.00195244404155917, 
0.00418380866048393, 0.00495084024823931, 0.000418380866048393, 
0.00299839620668015, 0.00174325360853497, 0.175441043162959, 
0.0593403528345304, 0.128303465588174, 0.0846523952304581, 0.0315877553866536, 
0.0635938916393557, 0, 0.00195244404155917, 0, 0.000836761732096785, 
0.00167352346419357, 0, 0.00348650721706994, 0.00648490342375009, 
0, 0.00732166515584687, 0.0221741859005648, 0.011017362805941, 
0.0055784115473119, 0.0194547102712503, 0.00843734746530925, 
0.000697301443413988, 0.000348650721706994, 0.00111568230946238, 
0.0139460288682798, 0.0439299909350812, 0.0322153266857262, 0.0057876019803361, 
0.0285196290356321, 0.0194547102712503, 0.00320758663970434, 
0.0057876019803361, 0.00460218952653232, 0.00864653789833345, 
0.0119238546823792, 0.0149919810334007, 0.00299839620668015, 
0.0059967924133603, 0.00543895125862911, 0.000836761732096785, 
0.00313785649536295, 0.00397461822745973, 0.00181298375287637, 
0.0423959277595705, 0.122167212886131, 0.00641517327940869, 0.011366013527648, 
0.043023499058643, 0.00055784115473119, 0.00474164981521512, 
0.00404434837180113, 0.00285893591799735, 0.0109476326615996, 
0.00774004602189527, 0.00174325360853497, 0.00432326894916673, 
0.00432326894916673, 0.0287985496129977, 0.046161355554006, 0.0174325360853497, 
0, 0.000488111010389792, 0, 0.000209190433024196, 0.000278920577365595, 
0, 0.00460218952653232, 0.00725193501150547, 0.00516003068126351, 
0.000906491876438184, 0.00502057039258071, 0.000767031587755387, 
0, 0.00167352346419357, 0.00181298375287637, 0.00369569765009414, 
0.00467191967087372, 0.00990168049647863, 0.00306812635102155, 
0.00997141064082003, 0.00390488808311833, 0.00648490342375009, 
0.00704274457848128, 0.00801896659926086, 0, 0.00132487274248658, 
0.00104595216512098, 0.00209190433024196, 0.00481137995955652, 
0.00913464890872324, 0.00453245938219092, 0.0057178718359947, 
0.00327731678404574, 0.00139460288682798, 0.00327731678404574, 
0, 0.00348650721706994, 0.00543895125862911, 0, 0.00411407851614253, 
0.00711247472282268, 0.00641517327940869, 0.010668712084234, 
0.0124816958371104, 0.0345861515933338, 0.000627571299072589, 
0.00230109476326616, 0, 0.00481137995955652, 0.0059270622690189, 
0.00153406317551077, 0.00174325360853497, 0.00285893591799735, 
0.00160379331985217, 0.00439299909350812, 0.00432326894916673, 
0.00390488808311833, 0, 0.00174325360853497, 0, 0.00341677707272854, 
0.0055784115473119, 0.0059270622690189, 0.00397461822745973, 
0.00801896659926086, 0.00132487274248658, 0.0131789972805244, 
0.0173628059410083, 0.0111568230946238, 0.024823931385538, 0.0611533365874067, 
0.0598284638449202, 0.00237082490760756, 0.00509030053692211, 
0.00411407851614253, 0.00864653789833345, 0.0104595216512098, 
0.00230109476326616, 0.0259396136950003, 0.0221044557562234, 
0.0130395369918416, 0.0160379331985217, 0.0124816958371104, 0.00432326894916673, 
0.0282407084582665, 0.0155498221881319, 0.00808869674360226, 
0.00216163447458336, 0.00481137995955652, 0, 0.136810543197824, 
0.141273272435674, 0.0616414475977965), Taxonomy = c("f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-1", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-1", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-1", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-1", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-1", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-1", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-2", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-2", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculum-2", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-3", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-3", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-3", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-4", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-4", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-4", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-5", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-5", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-5", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-6", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-6", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-6", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-7", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-7", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-7", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-8", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-8", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-8", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-9", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-9", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-9", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-10", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-10", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-10", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-11", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-11", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-11", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-12", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-12", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-12", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-13", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-13", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-13", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-14", 
"f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-14", "f__Muribaculaceae g__Muribaculaceae-14", 
"f__Eggerthellaceae g__Enterorhabdus", "f__Eggerthellaceae g__Enterorhabdus", 
"f__Eggerthellaceae g__Enterorhabdus", "f__Bifidobacteriaceae g__Bifidobacterium", 
"f__Bifidobacteriaceae g__Bifidobacterium", "f__Bifidobacteriaceae g__Bifidobacterium", 
"f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio", "f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio", 
"f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio", "f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio-1", 
"f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio-1", "f__Desulfovibrionaceae g__Desulfovibrio-1", 
"f__Moraxellaceae g__Acinetobacter", "f__Moraxellaceae g__Acinetobacter", 
"f__Moraxellaceae g__Acinetobacter", "f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas", 
"f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas", "f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas", 
"f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas-1", "f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas-1", 
"f__Pseudomonadaceae g__Pseudomonas-1", "f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia", 
"f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia", "f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia", 
"f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia-1", "f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia-1", 
"f__Peptostreptococcaceae g__Romboutsia-1", "f__Anaerovoracaceae g__[Eubacterium]_brachy_group", 
"f__Anaerovoracaceae g__[Eubacterium]_brachy_group", "f__Anaerovoracaceae g__[Eubacterium]_brachy_group", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1", "f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1", "f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1-1", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1-1", "f__Clostridiaceae g__Clostridium_sensu_stricto_1-1", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-1", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-1", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-1", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-2", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-2", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-2", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-3", 
"f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-3", "f__Erysipelotrichaceae g__Dubosiella-3", 
"f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus", "f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus", 
"f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus", "f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus-1", 
"f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus-1", "f__Lactobacillaceae g__Lactobacillus-1", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Candidatus_Arthromitus", "f__Clostridiaceae g__Candidatus_Arthromitus", 
"f__Clostridiaceae g__Candidatus_Arthromitus", "f__Ruminococcaceae g__Incertae_Sedis", 
"f__Ruminococcaceae g__Incertae_Sedis", "f__Ruminococcaceae g__Incertae_Sedis", 
"f__Ruminococcaceae g__Paludicola", "f__Ruminococcaceae g__Paludicola", 
"f__Ruminococcaceae g__Paludicola", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_FCS020_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Blautia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Blautia", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Blautia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_NK4A136_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__GCA-900066575", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__GCA-900066575", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__GCA-900066575", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__[Eubacterium]_xylanophilum_group-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Marvinbryantia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnospiraceae_UCG-006-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-3", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__uncultured-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-4", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-4", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-4", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-5", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-5", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-5", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__A2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__A2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__A2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Roseburia-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__-3", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-1", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-1", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-2", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-2", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-3", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-3", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-3", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-4", "f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-4", 
"f__Lachnospiraceae g__Lachnoclostridium-4"), ICI = c(1.92941176470588, 
1.92941176470588, 1.92941176470588, 1.36147757255937, 1.36147757255937, 
1.36147757255937, 0.627659574468085, 0.627659574468085, 0.627659574468085, 
0.504413619167718, 0.504413619167718, 0.504413619167718, 0.555555555555555, 
0.555555555555555, 0.555555555555555, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 0.396355353075171, 
0.396355353075171, 0.396355353075171, 0.378172588832487, 0.378172588832487, 
0.378172588832487, 0.428571428571429, 0.428571428571429, 0.428571428571429, 
0.342342342342342, 0.342342342342342, 0.342342342342342, 3.4, 
3.4, 3.4, 1.15384615384615, 1.15384615384615, 1.15384615384615, 
1.12933753943218, 1.12933753943218, 1.12933753943218, 23, 23, 
23, 1.29487179487179, 1.29487179487179, 1.29487179487179, 1.40740740740741, 
1.40740740740741, 1.40740740740741, 0.853040540540541, 0.853040540540541, 
0.853040540540541, 2.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 2.14285714285714, 
7.16666666666667, 7.16666666666667, 7.16666666666667, 0.338235294117647, 
0.338235294117647, 0.338235294117647, 0.373146622734761, 0.373146622734761, 
0.373146622734761, 28, 28, 28, 2, 2, 2, 1.86, 1.86, 1.86, 3.02857142857143, 
3.02857142857143, 3.02857142857143, 3.4875, 3.4875, 3.4875, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 3.15, 3.15, 3.15, 4.92771084337349, 4.92771084337349, 
4.92771084337349, 1.80434782608696, 1.80434782608696, 1.80434782608696, 
1.37903225806452, 1.37903225806452, 1.37903225806452, 2, 2, 2, 
3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 23.3846153846154, 23.3846153846154, 23.3846153846154, 
1.77173913043478, 1.77173913043478, 1.77173913043478, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 3.82926829268293, 3.82926829268293, 3.82926829268293, 2.48, 
2.48, 2.48, 1.60290556900726, 1.60290556900726, 1.60290556900726, 
7, 7, 7, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
1.57575757575758, 1.57575757575758, 1.57575757575758, 5.53846153846154, 
5.53846153846154, 5.53846153846154, 24, 24, 24, 1.26415094339623, 
1.26415094339623, 1.26415094339623, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 1.08602150537634, 
1.08602150537634, 1.08602150537634, 19, 19, 19, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 
1.26153846153846, 1.26153846153846, 1.26153846153846, 2.35, 2.35, 
2.35, 1.56, 1.56, 1.56, 1.72881355932203, 1.72881355932203, 1.72881355932203, 
1.16993464052288, 1.16993464052288, 1.16993464052288, 3.66666666666667, 
3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 1.23188405797101, 1.23188405797101, 
1.23188405797101, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 0.984126984126984, 0.984126984126984, 
0.984126984126984, 25, 25, 25, 1.63265306122449, 1.63265306122449, 
1.63265306122449, 2.01754385964912, 2.01754385964912, 2.01754385964912, 
1.31746031746032, 1.31746031746032, 1.31746031746032, 2.46348314606742, 
2.46348314606742, 2.46348314606742, 2.14705882352941, 2.14705882352941, 
2.14705882352941, 1.20967741935484, 1.20967741935484, 1.20967741935484, 
0.852150537634409, 0.852150537634409, 0.852150537634409, 0.778260869565217, 
0.778260869565217, 0.778260869565217, 0.550617283950617, 0.550617283950617, 
0.550617283950617, 2.2258064516129, 2.2258064516129, 2.2258064516129, 
1.03261977573904, 1.03261977573904, 1.03261977573904)), row.names = c(NA, 
-210L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried different variations such as:

```
g <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Sample_ID, y=Taxonomy, fill=Relative_abundance)) + 
  geom_tile(width=0.95, height=0.95) + 
  theme(axis.title=element_blank()) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position="left", plot.margin=unit(c(1,-0.1,1,1), "cm"))

g + scale_fill_gradientn(
  colors=c("black", "darkgreen", "green"),
  values=rescale(c(0,0.0005,1)),
  limits=c(0,1))
```

or

```
g + scale_fill_gradient2(
  low = "black", high = "green", mid = "darkgreen",
  name = "Relative abundance",
  midpoint = 0.0005, limit = c(0,1))
```

[image]

But the proportion of the colors did not change.

Thanks!

Comment: The scale is logarithmic, that's why the variations between 0 and 0.5 are much larger than in the end of the scale. Can you post the code that produces the plot `g` and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Thanks, how about now?