# ggplot2: colour in legend "out of bounds"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a heat map using `geom_tile` with a legend that shows the values of the colour gradient, with the following code:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(name = "log2(fold change)",
                             low = "navy",
                             mid = "white",
                             midpoint = 0,
                             high = "red",
                             breaks = c(-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4),
                             limits = c(-9,5),
                             guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour = "black", 
                                                    ticks.colour = "black",
                                                    barheight = 13.5))
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I have noticed that the red colour at the top range is not as it should be for `high = "red"`.
When I extend the limit to +9 (`limits = c(-9,9)`)I can see that the specified colour at the top range is correct:

[image]

How can I set the true `red` colour at upper limit 5?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that in the example code (I edited the original post to show the values of the breaks)

Comment: For asymmetric values around a midpoint you'll want `scale_fill_gradientn()` and the `scales::rescale()` convenience function.  See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301413/2461552).

Comment: That looks like a perfect duplicate to me. Let me know if that did not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks that seems to solve it.