# Two colors ordered heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

In this example
[R heatmap ggplot2 ordered as data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095276/r-heatmap-ggplot2-ordered-as-data-file)

I've changed data input to this one where for the second column every value is 0 so it should we filled in white

```
people,1,2,3
Ej1,1,0,0
Ej2,0,0,1
Ej3,0,0,1
Ej4,1,0,0
```

Using the same code as in the post

```
library(reshape2)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
 data.m = melt(data)
 data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
  data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
 p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), 
                                                   colour =   "white") 
 p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")
```

But the X2 variable column is filled with a different color instead of white as shown in the image.

I've been trying to change the `scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue")` to the `scale_color_gradient` but couldn't find out how.

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be how `rescale` is being applied to your data frame. For a vector `x`, `rescale(x)` checks if the range of `x` is `0`, and if this is the case it will use the `mean` of the `to` range, whose default value is `to=c(0,1)`:

```
rescale(rep(0,4),to=c(0,1))
[1] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

When `ddply` applies the `.FUN` `rescale` to your data frame, when it considers variable `X2`, the range of `value` is `0`, as in case above.

The `rescale` column in `data.m` is showing a value of `0.5` for `X2`, explained by the above. So the `ggplot` is plotting the data correctly.

```
   people variable value rescale
1     Ej1       X1     1     1.0
2     Ej2       X1     0     0.0
3     Ej3       X1     0     0.0
4     Ej4       X1     1     1.0
5     Ej1       X2     0     0.5
6     Ej2       X2     0     0.5
7     Ej3       X2     0     0.5
8     Ej4       X2     0     0.5
9     Ej1       X3     0     0.0
10    Ej2       X3     1     1.0
11    Ej3       X3     1     1.0
12    Ej4       X3     0     0.0
```

One way around this is to dump the use of `ddply` here, and just operate on the data frame directly, forcing `rescale` to operate on the entire `value` column (rather than via `.(variables)`) and so avoiding the 0 range problem for `X2`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
data.m = melt(data)
#data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
data.m[,"rescale"]<-rescale(data.m[,"value"],to=c(0,1))
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour =   "white")+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue") 
p
```

[image: ggplot of data.m based on fruit.txt data]

Comment: ^ No problem. Please come again